# Extract data from MDX query string

Tags: c#, regex

I have hundreds of MDX queries captured from SQL Analysis Services (Extended Events).

They look like this :

```
SELECT {[Measures].[ Count - Sales],[Measures].[ Count - Customers],[Measures].[Revenue]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY Hierarchize(DrilldownMember({{DrilldownMember({{DrilldownLevel({[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}}, {[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].&[2014],[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].&[2015],[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].&[2016],[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].&[2017],[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].&[2018],[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].&[2013]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}},
```

I need to write a bit of c# to extract data as :

```
[Measures].[ Count - Sales]
[Measures].[ Count - Customers]
[Measures].[Revenue]
[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[All]
[DimDate].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year]
```

etc..

I don't mind if I get repeating members.

I can rely ranges being :
[Measures] to second ]
[Dim to second or third ]

I'm leaning towards using Regex to extract data :

Any ideas on the regex to capture above elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
\[[^\]]+\]\.\[[^\]]+\](\.\[[^\]]+\])?
```

Explanation:

`\[[^\]]+\]` - open bracket, anything until close bracket, close bracket (let's call it BRACKETED).

It's followed by dot, and another BRACKETED. Last section of dot and BRACKETED is optional.